# Where to supply authentication details to the Network Proxy (Central Proxy) on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, gnome, authentication, proxy, squid

My system is running Fedora 16 and I live in a campus where we use LAN to connect to the Internet. And for this, we use an http proxy with authentication (username & password).
I tried putting the `proxyaddress:port` in the Network Proxy settings after going to the Network Settings window. However, it never asked for an authentication and the programs that use the internet are unable connect, except for Firefox because it asks for authentication.
Also, I could get Yum to work by manually editing `yum.conf`. I even tried using `http://username:password@proxy:port` like in the Yum configuration but it has not helped.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: [The GNOME manual](http://library.gnome.org/users/user-guide/2.32/prefs-networkproxy.html.en) mentions a **Details** button in Network Proxy settings, have you tried this?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such **Details** button. Atleast not in Fedora 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many, but not all, programs honor the environment variables `http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, `ftp_proxy`, and `no_proxy`. You could add them to your `~/.bashrc` .

```
export http_proxy="http://username:password@yourproxy:port"
export https_proxy="http://username:password@yourproxy:port"
export ftp_proxy="http://username:password@yourproxy:port"
export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1"
```

Some programs, like `yum`, will require the proxy information in a certain way and will need to be configured on an individual basis.

It's also possible to manually set proxy settings in Gnome3 by using `gsettings` because some programs, like Chromium, will honor those settings. See `man gsettings` and `gsettings help` for more information.

```
# gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.system.proxy
org.gnome.system.proxy autoconfig-url ''
org.gnome.system.proxy ignore-hosts ['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8']
org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'
org.gnome.system.proxy use-same-proxy true
org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp host ''
org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp port 0
org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-password ''
org.gnome.system.proxy.http authentication-user ''
org.gnome.system.proxy.http enabled false
org.gnome.system.proxy.http host ''
org.gnome.system.proxy.http port 8080
org.gnome.system.proxy.http use-authentication false
org.gnome.system.proxy.https host ''
org.gnome.system.proxy.https port 0
org.gnome.system.proxy.socks host ''
org.gnome.system.proxy.socks port 0
```